# avoid giving userid/pass in connection string

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, web-config, connection-string, database-connection

im using a shared hosting company to host my site and db.
they are both being hosted on the same server.

to access the db i am currently supplying  userid and password in the connection string within the web config.

this just makes me really uncomfortable.

is there i way to avoid giving userid/pass in web.config connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to OS authentication:

> Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial
>   Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;

In this case grant db access to the account your site runs under. Or, just [encrypt your connectionStrings section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx) in web.config.

**Update:**
I'm not sure how this happens in hosting environments (the hoster should have some FAQ), but if your server is dedicated one and you have administrative privilegies on your Sql Server you can do that like

```
create login [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] from windows
create user [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] for login [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader',[NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]
```

The account to grant access to is one the application pool in IIS is running under. NetworkService is default for IIS 6.0 but if the server is shared you probably have a custom account (granting access to NetworkService on shared server will expose your db to any service running under NetworkAccount).

Comment: how do i grant db access? does encrypting/decrypting impact performance?

Comment: raklos, i've updated my answer on how to grant access to IIS working account. As for encrypting/decrypting performance i didn't see noticeable difference in practice. As far as i understand it only happens once when the run-time is instantiating application domain.